# Return 2 objects using an IIFE

Tags: javascript, function, object, null, return

I'm trying to return 2 objects using an IIFE. I cant find whats wrong here.

```
var UIController = (function(){

    return{
        getMinput: function(){
            return {
            mstaff1: document.querySelector('#mstaff1').value,
            mstaff2: document.querySelector('#mstaff2').value,
            mpda: document.querySelector('#mpda').value,
            mpos: document.querySelector('#mpos').value,
            mcash: document.querySelector('#mcash').value,
            mtotal: document.querySelector('#mtotal').value
            };
        }


        getMinput: function(){
            return {
            mstaff1: document.querySelector('#mstaff1').value,
            mstaff2: document.querySelector('#mstaff2').value,
            mpda: document.querySelector('#mpda').value,
            mpos: document.querySelector('#mpos').value,
            mcash: document.querySelector('#mcash').value,
            mtotal: document.querySelector('#mtotal').value
            };
        }   
    };

})();
```

Comment: Looks like you are returning one object, composed of two methods.

Comment: Actually, no, just one method, as you are repeating the id in the object.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you have one object. You can't have the same name for methods inside one object. Also, you need to add ',' after each method or prop.
So do it like this:

```
(function(){

    return{
        getMinput: function(){
            return {
            mstaff1: document.querySelector('#mstaff1').value,
            mstaff2: document.querySelector('#mstaff2').value,
            mpda: document.querySelector('#mpda').value,
            mpos: document.querySelector('#mpos').value,
            mcash: document.querySelector('#mcash').value,
            mtotal: document.querySelector('#mtotal').value
            };
        },

        getMinput1: function(){
            return {
            mstaff1: document.querySelector('#mstaff1').value,
            mstaff2: document.querySelector('#mstaff2').value,
            mpda: document.querySelector('#mpda').value,
            mpos: document.querySelector('#mpos').value,
            mcash: document.querySelector('#mcash').value,
            mtotal: document.querySelector('#mtotal').value
            };
        }   
    };
    })());

OR if you really need two objects you can use array: 

(function(){
    return [
        getMinput: function(){
            return {
            mstaff1: document.querySelector('#mstaff1').value,
            mstaff2: document.querySelector('#mstaff2').value,
            mpda: document.querySelector('#mpda').value,
            mpos: document.querySelector('#mpos').value,
            mcash: document.querySelector('#mcash').value,
            mtotal: document.querySelector('#mtotal').value
            };
        },


        getMinput1: function(){
            return {
            mstaff1: document.querySelector('#mstaff1').value,
            mstaff2: document.querySelector('#mstaff2').value,
            mpda: document.querySelector('#mpda').value,
            mpos: document.querySelector('#mpos').value,
            mcash: document.querySelector('#mcash').value,
            mtotal: document.querySelector('#mtotal').value
            };
        }   
    ];
  })
());
```

Comment: `(key: function, key2: function)` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two returns from a single run of a function. That's physically impossible.
But you can return an *array* of values.

```
     var UIController = (function ... return [ /*whatever porcesing*/ , /*second result */ ]; .. })();
```